# Prove $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ and $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$ are homeomorphic to each other

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$ and $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$ and need to prove they are homeomorphic to each other. I wanted to use the function $f: (x,y) \mapsto (\frac 1x, \frac 1y)$ but am not sure it's continuous even with $(0,0)$ excluded. What can I use instead?

Comment: $f$ _is_ continuous on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. No need to retreat from that :)

Comment: Hint: Think about the inversion $J(z)=1/z$, $z$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 1):

Use it, it is continuous. All basic operations ($+,-,\cdot,/$) are continuous *in their domain of definition*.
**But:** Though taking inverse is th eright idea, you did something wrong (your $f$ is not defined at $(x,0)$ or $(0,x)$ for example. You want to map a point at distance $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to a point at distance $\frac1r$

Comment: And the map does not send one domain to the other and vice versa, at all...